# What is the maximum value in a signal long 32 bit-integer

Tags: computer-science

I tried to Convert the maximum value in a signed long 32-bit integer representing hundreds of a second and the got 9223372036854775807 divided by 518400, but the answer I got was 1.7791999e+13. I am supposed to divide the remainder by 21600. How can I do that>

Answer (score 1):

2,147,483,647 for signed integer. 4,294,967,295 for unsigned integer.

32 bit means 32 binary digits. There are 4,294,967,296 possible combinations. One of the combinations is zero.

Binary is base 2 which means that you add a digit when you get to 2, instead of when you get to 10 as in base 10 counting.